# How to Create a Custom Element with a Shadow Root Already Attached

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Having a simple custom element

```
document.registerElement('x-foo', {
    prototype: HTMLElement.prototype;
});
```

I can create an HTML node

```
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

then select it in JavaScript, and attach a shadow root.

```
var xFoo = document.querySelector('x-foo')[0];
var root = xFoo.createShadowRoot();
root.textContent = 'I am a shadow root';
```

However, I would like the objects to be created with a predefined
shadow root, without any JavaScript manipulations afterwards, as it is with
`<input>` and other user-agent defined nodes.

How would I define a constructor or something for my element in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Question is a bit old, but putting this answer here in case you haven't figured it out yet.

There are 4 lifecycle callback methods associated with custom elements. Copying from this nice [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) on html5rocks.

[image]

So to answer you question, you can put your code to attach a shadow-root to custom element inside createdCallback and it will be executed every time your x-code element is initialized.
This is a sort of constructor for your custom element.

Hope it helps.